# Laravel rename a directory using Storage facade

Tags: laravel

I'd like to rename a directory with the Storage Facade (S3 object). I've tried using `move` and `rename`, both with and without trailing slash, none of these work.

```php
Storage::disk('s3')->move($dir_temp, $dir_final);
Storage::disk('s3')->move($dir_temp.'/', $dir_final.'/');
Storage::disk('s3')->rename($dir_temp, $dir_final);
Storage::disk('s3')->rename($dir_temp.'/', $dir_final.'/');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did use `rename` function, and it did work for renaming a directory.

This code worked for renaming directory `dir 1` to `dir 2`:

```
  Storage::disk('movies')->rename('dir 1', 'dir 2');
```

Now, it depends on what error did you get.

- make sure, you have `rwx` rights to the parent directory
- make sure the source directory exists, and the destination does not
- make sure the name is valid for a name, for example, windows OS will not allow certain characters in the name
- make sure you do have permissions to the source directory for that operation
- be very carefull with slashes, as windows OS has different path slashes than linux.

For the directory separator, to be platform independent, you can use

```
$DS = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
```

Also, the permissions can be quite tricky, as, if you have the app deployed, traditionally, the `http` user is the user under which all the code is executed, so keep that in mind.